# databinding list to asp.net dropdown control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

Good Morning.
I have a dropdown list control which when a particular item is selected, another dropdown's list is populated based on that selection. The code behind is below.

```
Imports System.IO
Partial Class Data
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Private Property _futureslist As List(Of String)
Property FuturesList As List(Of String)
    Get
        Return _futureslist
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of String))
        Dim strText As String =    File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/DataFiles/AvailableFutures.txt"))
        Dim arytext() As String = strText.Split(",")
        For i As Integer = 0 To arytext.Count - 1
            value.Add(arytext(i))
        Next
        _futureslist = value
    End Set

End Property
Protected Sub ddlMain_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlMain.SelectedIndexChanged
    If Not IsPostBack Then

        If ddlMain.SelectedItem.Text = "Futures" Then
            ddlMainsub1.DataSource = _futureslist
            ddlMainsub1.DataBind()

        End If
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

The file it's reading to create the list property is formatted as follows;
Corn,
Wheat,
Coffee

So when the main dropdown selected item is "Futures" the second dropdown values are databound to the FuturesList property. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

set `AutoPostBack=True` of "ddlMain" and then at

```
Protected Sub ddlMain_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlMain.SelectedIndexChanged
 ddlMainsub1.Items.Clear()
 'bound items here to DropDownList2
End Sub
```

Hope It Helps. Good Luck.

Comment: May be you need to remove "If Not IsPostBack Then"
checking

Comment: Autopsy? My version of .NET doesn't do that. Looks like someone has Autocorrect = true on their phone. =)

Comment: you didnt know that autopsy = autopostback ((-;

Comment: @dinotom ::did you succeeded ?